# WordPress - Apperance > Menu

Tags: menus, pages

How do I use the menu on the dashboard under Appearance > Menu - http://prntscr.com/5052sl

The one I'm using is based on page arrangement, so all my pages are displayed on the menu under some pages.

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'sort_column'    => 'menu_order', 
    'container'      => false,
    'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 
    'exclude'        => '479' 
) );
```

I want to use the menu on the Appearance tab, but I don't know how to call my menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the codex documentation page about the [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) you will see that there is a param called `menu`, and that will allow you to target a specific menu.

As pointed on the documentation you can check this:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    // Use this menu
    'menu' => 'Project Nav',

    // do not fall back to first non-empty menu
    'theme_location' => '__no_such_location'

    // do not fall back to wp_page_menu()
    'fallback_cb' => false
);
```

But if you want to register a place I mean `theme_location`, you need to [`register_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu) then a new *Widget* will appear on the Appearance tab and you will be able to select which menu goes to that location registered.

---

You just need to place this on your theme `functions.php` and head over to the "Appearance" > "Menu" on the Wordpress Admin and select the menu you want to be assigned to the Primary Menu.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'q166543_register_menu' );
function q166543_register_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary Menu' );
}
```

Then head over to the place you want to display the menu and paste the following code:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    'container'      => false,
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'exclude'        => '479',


    // do not fall back to wp_page_menu()
    'fallback_cb' => false
);
```

Comment: can you guide me in laymans I don't know much about php and it's very hard for me to understand that.

Comment: Hi @MichaelPon I've edited my answer now it has a guide to solve the problem.

Comment: I have now added my custom menu from the widget area. thanks i forgot to look at my widget tab.

Comment: does this only adds an extra widget area? I'm thinking about the menu name do i have to match anything on my files with the ones you posted?

Comment: I didn't understand what you said.